# Let $G$ be a group show that $φ:G\rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> The function  $φ:G\rightarrow G$ defined by $φ(a) = a^2$ is a group homomorphism.

I know the definition of a group homomorphism but I don't know how to manipulate the given information to complete the proof.

Comment: It isn't always a group homomorphism.

Comment: $G$ is abelian...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement holds if the group is abelian, because then\begin{align}\phi(ab)&=(ab)^2\\&=(ab)(ab)\\&=a\bigl(b(ab)\bigr)\\&=a\bigl((ba)b\bigr)\\&=a\bigl((ab)b\bigr)\\&=a\bigl(a(ab)\bigr)\\&=a^2b^2\\&=\phi(a)\phi(b).\end{align}However, in is *not* true in general. For instance, considere the group $S_3$ of all permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$. Then$$\phi\bigl((12)(13)\bigr)=\phi(132)=(132)^2=(123),$$whereas$$\phi(12)\phi(13)=e.e=e.$$

Comment: How did you figure out that G must be abelian so that the statement hold ?

Comment: @hjx Because $a^2.b^2=(a.b)^2\iff a.a.b.b=a.b.a.b\iff a.b=b.a$.

Answer (score 0):

It is  a homomorphism if $G$ is a multiplicative abelian group.

Note that $(ab)=abab$ and if $G$ is multiplicative and if it is also abelian then $ab=a^2b^2$

So for a counterexample use  a non abelia group.

Take a group of matrices..

Thus $\phi$ is not always a homomorphism.

Comment: In $(\Bbb R, +)$, we have $\varphi(a) = a+a$. The $^2$ refers to the group operation, not some other multiplication operation you might happen to know about on $G$.

Comment: Your exemple is wrong, because $\phi(a+b)=(a+b)+(a+b)=(a+a)+(b+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$. As you stated yourself, the statment is true if the group is abelian, and $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is abelian.

Comment: OK i will delete that part with the reals

Comment: I edited the asnwer